# Matlab piecewise two variables function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot a piecewise function  of two variables, but the code I write doesn't work.

This is my code

```
c=-0.5;
b=0.5;
L=0:1:100;
K=0:1:100;
[L,K]= meshgrid(L,K);

for i=1:length(L)
    for q=1:length(K)
            if 
            {
            L(i)/K(q)>=-c
            Z=(K(q).^b).*(L(i)+(b.*c).*K(q)).^(1-b);
            else
            Z=((-1/c)^b) .*(1-b).*(1-b);
            }
            end
    end
end
surf(Z)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with your code is the use of the curly braces `{ ... }`. Unlike in many other programming languages (e.g. C or Java), you do not need any curly braces to group multiple commands together (e.g. in an if or a for clause). Instead, MATLAB uses the `end` statement as shown below.

Second, in each iteration you write `Z = ...`, which `Z` is overwritten in each iteration. That way, you will get one single number `Z` at the end of your code. Instead, you should use [matrix indexing](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) to write the result of your calculation to the `(i,q)`-th position in `Z`. This is as simple as writing `Z(i,q) = ...;`. While this would already work, you should [preallocate](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) your `Z` matrix, that means you create a matrix of zeros before the for loop. Then MATLAB doesn't have to increase the size of your matrix in each iteration. This is done using the [`zeros`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) function.

Third, you have to call `surf(L,K,Z)` instead of `surf(Z)` to get the axis right: with `surf(Z)`, they will be from 1 to 101, while they should go from 0 to 100.

As proposed in the previous (now deleted) answer, you do not need to explicitly write `.*` instead of `*`, as you are dealing with scalars and not with vectors or matrices. You only need `.*` if you want to calculate a point-wise multiplication between two vectors/matrices of the same size. With scalars, both works and leads to the same results, but it is not needed at all.

Then, don't use `length`. `length` just returns the length of the *largest* array dimension. If you change `K` to go from 0 to 1000, or make steps of size 0.1, this will fail. Instead, use `size` to get the length in a specified dimension. Use the first dimension for `i` and the second dimension for `q`.

One more hint: [don't use `i` or `j` as variables in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/4221706), as they are used to denote the imaginary unit. Just use `ii` or `k` or any other name you like. In my opinion, using `i` and `j` in for loops is a bad habit - rather use some meaningful names, like `rowNumber` or `imageNumber`, or whatever is applicable in your case - so somebody reading the code knows what this *really* is.

```
c=-0.5;
b=0.5;
L=0:1:100;
K=0:1:100;
[L,K]= meshgrid(L,K);

% Preallocate Z
Z = zeros(size(L,1), size(K,2));

for ii=1:size(L,1)
    for q=1:size(K,2)
        if L(ii)/K(q)>=-c
            Z(ii,q) = (K(q)^b)*(L(ii)+(b*c)*K(q))^(1-b);
        else
            Z(ii,q) =((-1/c)^b)*(1-b)*(1-b);
        end
    end
end

surf(L,K,Z)
```

With that, your code runs through without any errors and creates a surface plot as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime example of where vectorized (all-in-one-operation) matlab coding can bring great benefits in terms of efficiency:

```
c=-0.5;
b=0.5;
L=0:1:100;
K=0:1:100;

% slow loop-based method - shouldn't use meshgridded L and K here
Z = zeros(length(L), length(K));
for i=1:length(L)
    for q=1:length(K)
        if L(i)/K(q)>=-c
            Z(i,q) = (K(q)^b)*(L(i)+(b*c)*K(q))^(1-b);
        else
            Z(i,q) =((-1/c)^b)*(1-b)*(1-b);
        end
    end
end
figure(1)
surf(L,K,Z)



% much faster vectorized approach
ZZ = zeros(length(L), length(K));
[KK,LL]= meshgrid(K, L);  % corrected order of meshgrid inputs and outputs
                          % ---alternatively you could use [LL,KK]=ndgrid(L,K);
case1 = LL ./ KK >= -c;
case2 = ~case1;
ZZ(case1) = KK(case1).^b .* ( LL(case1) + (b*c) .* KK(case1) ) .^ (1 - b);
ZZ(case2) = ((-1/c)^b)*(1-b)*(1-b);

figure(2)
surf(L,K,ZZ)
```